# Round off numbers in python

Tags: python, list, numbers, append, rounding

I have a list of numbers [0,10,20,30,40,50] now this list will be appended by random numbers such as 33 ,43,I have to check the list every time it appends no to the list and i want them to be rounded off to 30 and 40.

Comment: why not round them before appending, it would be a whole lot faster, can you show us your code?

Comment: For rounding, you can use builtin `round` with negative precision, e.g. `round(34.567, -1)`

Comment: I can't control what numbers that will be appended to a list.But i have to make to sure they are rounded off.

Comment: I can't control what's being appended to a list.So I want them to be rounded off after appending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) built-in function. In conjuction with a *list comprehension*, can give us an expressive one-line function!

```
def round_list(l):
    return [int(round(i, -1)) for i in l]
```

**Sample output:**

```
l = [24, 34, 41, 40, 12, 434, 53, 53]
print round_list(l)
>>> [20, 30, 40, 40, 10, 430, 50, 50]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast.How do I check whether values in list are rounded off to 20,30,40?

Comment: There's no need to check whether or not the values are rounded to the nearest 10, as this function returns a new list where each element is always rounded to the nearest 10th.

Answer (score 1):

In order to round to the nearest 10 you can:

1. Divide the number by 10
2. Use [round()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) on the new number
3. Multiply the rounded number by 10

The code below should contain what you need:

```
import random

l = [0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0]

# generate a random number
random_number = random.uniform(30, 100)

# round the number to nearest 10
def round_number(num):
    x = round(num/10) * 10
    return x

rounded_number = round_number(random_number)

# append to the list
l.append(rounded_number)
```

Testing the above:

```
>>> print random_number
64.566245501
>>> print rounded_number
60.0
>>> print l
[0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0]
```